# C# / .NET4.7.2. Как вывести составную картинку из 3-х Bitmap-ов в pictureBox в процессе видеозахвата с web-камеры. (Использую библиотеку AForge.)

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, web-camera

Видимо, что-то не правильно делаю. Не судите строго, я далеко не профи.

Если вкратце: нужно соединить 3 битмапа в один, вывести результат в PictureBox. Одна из картинок - кадр из web-камеры. Соответственно соединять нужно в событии по кадру, каждый раз.

Сначала использовал библиотеку Emgu, сейчас AForge, но всякий раз вылетают критические ошибки. Иногда программа запускается и какое-то время работает, иногда даже долго, а иногда еще до запуска ошибка.
На данный момент такая:
**"System.ArgumentException" в System.Drawing.dll Недопустимый параметр**
Подозреваю, что возникают конфликтные ситуации, т.к. в программе используется таймер (), событие Form_Paint, и, собственно, событие кадра с web-камеры NewFrameEventArgs, в котором и производится слияние всех Bitmap и вывод в PictureBox.
В глобальных переменных находится большой массив с картинками, инициализируются они в процессе работы программы. Сами картинки хранятся в отдельной папке в каталоге проекта, вызываются по имени (массив имен типа String) из ресурсов, где они все прикреплены. Весь код пару тысяч строк, привожу основные моменты. Глобальные переменные:

```
    //  Глобальные переменные (для WebCam)
    private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;
    //  картинки
    Bitmap[] arrBmpWebCam = new Bitmap[1023];
    //  массив имен картинок из ресурсов для картинок
    string[] strFileNames_2 = new string[1024] {
        "_01x", "_02x", "_03x".......};
    //  индекс для массива (выше). Принимает разные значения по таймеру
    int ImgIndex = 0;
    //  Битмапы для наложения картинок
    //  не изменяющаяся картинка
    Bitmap maskBmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._MaskAur, DB.pb_WebCam_Size);
    //  картинка кадр из web-камеры
    Bitmap baseBmp;
    //  пустой битмап для склейки всех картинок и вывода в pictureBox
    Bitmap WebCam_rezultBmp = new Bitmap(DB.pb_WebCam_Size.Width, DB.pb_WebCam_Size.Height,
                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

В таймере меняется значение *ImgIndex* (индекс массива имен картинок из ресурсов):

```
    private void timer_Interval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { ImgIndex = x; // постоянно изменяющееся значение}
```

**Главный виновник ошибок** - событие по кадру:

```
    private void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //  сборка мусора
        if (pb_WebCam.Image != null) pb_WebCam.Image.Dispose();
          
        try
        {
            //  запись картинки в массив из ресурсов по индексу
            arrBmpWebCam[ImgIndex] = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(strFileNames_2[ImgIndex]), pb_WebCam.Size);
            //  запись картинки кадра из камеры
            baseBmp = new Bitmap((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), pb_WebCam.Size);
            //  слияние 3-х картинок
            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(WebCam_rezultBmp);
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

            graphics.DrawImage(baseBmp, 0, 0);  //  кадр из камеры
            graphics.DrawImage(maskBmp, 0, 0);  //  картинка, инициализированная в глобальных переменных
            graphics.DrawImage((Bitmap)SetImageOpacity(arrBmpWebCam[ImgIndex], 0.3f), 0, 0);  //  картинка из
            //ресурсов (используется функция, увеличивающая прозрачность)
            //  вывод в PictureBox
            pb_WebCam.Image = WebCam_rezultBmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Frame_Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Код функции, увеличивающей прозрачность (взял из интернета, источник уже не помню. Ф-ция рабочая):

```
        public Image SetImageOpacity(Image image, float opacity)
        {
            try
            {
                //create a Bitmap the size of the image provided  
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
                //create a graphics object from the image  
                using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    //create a color matrix object  
                    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
                    //set the opacity  
                    matrix.Matrix33 = opacity;
                    //create image attributes  
                    ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
                    //set the color(opacity) of the image  
                    attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
                    //now draw the image  
                    gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
                }
                return bmp;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Если в коде события по кадру оставить следующий код, то все прекрасно работает, ошибок нет:

```
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    pb_WebCam.Image = img;
```

Но мне нужно совместить 3 картинки. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Непонятно, как ответить на этот вопрос, потому что непонятно, что вообще происходит в этом коде.

Comment: @aepot, ошибка, скорее всего, в событии FinalVideo_NewFrame - это событие по кадру из веб-камеры (Ошибка: Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentException" в System.Drawing.dll
Недопустимый параметр.). Если оставить просто вывод кадра в PictureBox - все работает. Мне нужно объединить 3 картинки с разной степенью прозрачности в одну и вывести в PictureBox. Типа трансляция видео из вебки с наложенными эффектами, можно так сказать

Comment: В какой строчке кода ошибка - надо догадаться?

Comment: @aepot, ошибка выскакивает в режиме приостановки выполнения, строку не подсвечивает

Comment: А в трассировке стека тогда что?

Comment: @aepot Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]

Comment: А не может быть так, что при обработке буфера с предыдущим кадром камера уже начинает туда писать следующий кадр? Может, тогда делать обработку всегда на КОПИИ буфера? или вставить lock перед обработкой буфера?

Comment: Ставьте точку останова на первую строчку метода и выполняйте пошагово, пока не упадет.

Comment: @aepot, ставил, падает в начале события на try {...}.
Если оставить так:
if (pb_WebCam.Image != null) pb_WebCam.Image.Dispose();
            baseBmp = new Bitmap((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), DB.pb_WebCam_Size);
            pb_WebCam.Image = baseBmp;
то картинка выводится с вебки без ошибок

Comment: @S.H., не должно, ведь работает, когда локальная переменная bitmap в событии передается в PictureBox

Comment: @aepot, в предыдущем комментарии не правильно написал. Так работает иногда, но ошибка появляется все равно. Без ошибки так (без создания нового объекта Bitmap):
Bitmap frameBmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pb_WebCam.Image = frameBmp;

Comment: чем по-вашему отличается `baseBmp = new Bitmap((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), pb_WebCam.Size);` и `baseBmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();`? И вообще если уж идти по первому варианту, то надо `baseBmp = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, pb_WebCam.Size);` И что такое `baseBmp`, почему эта переменная не локальная? Быть может в этом проблема.

Comment: @aepot, в первом случае создается новый объект, ему присваивается размер PictureBox-а. Самому PictureBox задается размер в коде при событии FormLoad (может, это имеет значение). Во втором случае новый объект не создается. baseBmp - глобальная переменная типа Bitmap, в событии по кадру ей присваивается картинка кадра из вебки.
baseBmp = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, pb_WebCam.Size); - так тоже с прежней  ошибкой

Comment: @aepot, может быть такое, что в событии по кадру (FinalVideo_NewFrame) не успевают отработать другие функции, а это событие уже вызывается снова, с приходом нового кадра? Или оно не может быть вызвано, пока не будет выполнен весь код внутри этого события?

Comment: Сделайте эту переменную локальной. И если проблема в многопоточке, сделайте так: вместо `pb_WebCam.Image = WebCam_rezultBmp;` вот так `Invoke((Action)(() => pb_WebCam.Image = WebCam_rezultBmp));`. Ну и про `new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, pb_WebCam.Size);` не забудьте, потому что у вас лишнее клонирование битмапов.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо! убрал клонирование в `new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, pb_WebCam.Size);`, кроме того, перенес создание всех объектов Bitmap из глобальных переменных в событие по кадру, при этом сами битмапы глобальные. Добавил везде проверки на `!= null` при слиянии всех 3-х картинок и выводе готовой картинки в PictureBox , без проверок не работает. Вроде больше не появляются ошибки. Работает без многопоточки.

Comment: @Faust напишите ответ на свой вопрос, какой в итоге код получился в тех функциях, где он менялся, чтобы это в будущем помогло другим людям. И отметьте как принятый ответ.

Comment: @Blackmeser, хорошо, спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: @aepot, большое спасибо! ваши комментарии помогли справиться с проблемой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменения в глобальных переменных - объявление Bitmap-ов без инициализации:

```
    //  Глобальные переменные (для WebCam)
    //  не изменяющаяся картинка
    Bitmap maskBmp;
    //  картинка кадр из web-камеры
    Bitmap baseBmp;
    //  пустой битмап для склейки всех картинок и вывода в pictureBox
    Bitmap WebCam_rezultBmp;
```

Изменения в событии по кадру - убрал строку `if (pb_WebCam.Image != null) pb_WebCam.Image.Dispose();`, вместо `eventArgs.Frame.Clone()` - просто `eventArgs.Frame`, добавил буферную локальную переменную, принимающую кадр `Bitmap frameBmp = eventArgs.Frame;`, всем Bitmap-ам присваиваются значения в данном событии, при объединении 3-х Bitmap-ов `baseBmp`, `maskBmp` и `arrBmpWebCam[auraImgIndex]` в один `WebCam_rezultBmp`, а так же при присвоении картинки PictureBox-у `pb_WebCam` добавлены проверки на `!= null`:

```
    private void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                arrBmpWebCam[ImgIndex] = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.
                    GetObject(strFileNames_2[ImgIndex]), DB.pb_WebCam_Size);

                Bitmap frameBmp = eventArgs.Frame;

                baseBmp = new Bitmap(frameBmp, DB.pb_WebCam_Size);

                maskBmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._Mask, DB.pb_WebCam_Size);

                WebCam_rezultBmp = new Bitmap(DB.pb_WebCam_Size.Width, DB.pb_WebCam_Size.Height,
                            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(WebCam_rezultBmp);
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

                if (baseBmp != null)
                    graphics.DrawImage(baseBmp, 0, 0);

                if (maskBmp != null)
                    graphics.DrawImage(maskBmp, 0, 0);

                if (arrBmpWebCam[ImgIndex] != null)
                    graphics.DrawImage((Bitmap)SetImageOpacity(arrBmpWebCam[ImgIndex], 0.3f), 0, 0);

                if (WebCam_rezultBmp != null)
                    pb_WebCam.Image = WebCam_rezultBmp;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Frame_Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Так никаких ошибок больше не возникает.

Comment: `if (WebCam_rezultBmp != null)` лишняя проверка, здесь никогда null не будет, угадайте, почему. `baseBmp` `maskBmp` - тоже проверки лишние. Еще здесь скорее всего много лишенй работы делается, которую каждый кадр не надо делать. Например `new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._Mask, DB.pb_WebCam_Size);` если в процессе вызовов метода `pb_WebCam_Size` не меняется, то и битмап, получившийся в этой строчке один и тот же. Тогда стоит вынести его создание из метода. Остальные операции проверьте на этот же признак.

Comment: Еще, если вам нужна производительность - переходите на .NET 5. Фреймворк 4.x уже сильно устарел.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо! Да, конечно, есть что оптимизировать. Главное, ошибки не вылезают, 3 дня пытался избавиться.